# Load csv file and create nodes and reletionships

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I've a csv file like the sample below and I want to import that into Neo4j and create nodes and relationships.

```
"N_ID","Name","Relationship","A_ID","Address"
"N_01","John Doe","resident","A_01","1138  Mapleview Drive"
"N_02","Jane Doe","resident","A_01","1138  Mapleview Drive"
"N_03","Randall L Russo","visitor","A_02","866  Sweetwood Drive"
"N_04","Sam B Haley","resident","A_03","152  Point Street"
"N_01","John Doe","mailing address","A_04",3490  Horizon Circle"
```

'm able to create nodes using the code below but i don't know how to create the relationships based on the csv file.

```
using PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
‘File://contacts.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Person {ID:line.N_ID, name:line.Name})
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE (:Person {N_ID:line.N_ID, Name:line.Name})-[:line.Relationship]-> (:Address {A_ID:line.A_ID, Address:line.Address})
```

Please bear with me  I'm new to Neo4j.

Comment: Setting Relationship like this is not allowed. Please check case-when-then for this.

Comment: @Raj :can you please give a little more explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the **[apoc plugin](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/)** and try this query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file://contacts.csv' AS line
MERGE (p1:Person {N_ID:line.N_ID})
ON CREATE SET p1.Name=line.Name
MERGE (a1:Address {A_ID:line.A_ID})
ON CREATE SET a1.Address=line.Address
WITH a1,p1,line
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(p1,line.Relationship,{},{},a1) YIELD rel
RETURN count(*);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example. I've installed the apoc plugin (and restarted) but I get an error on this line `CALL apoc.merge.relationship(p1,line.Relationship,{},{},a1) YIELD rel` `Variable 'line' not defined`

Comment: I've noticed that there's an individual node and relationship for every line. I expected that the node for `John Doe` was connected to `A_01` and `A_04` and `Jane Doe` from `N_02` also to `A_01`

Comment: N_ID ans A_ID are unique ids for person and address, right?

Comment: Indeed, N_ID ans A_ID are unique ids for person and address